# Is it possible to change flextable default font from arial

Tags: r, fonts, flextable, officer

I love David Gohel's Officer and Flextable packages and they are really a flexible alternative to write word document reports with complex layouts which are not achievable in R markdown.

I have created custom styles for paragraphs and tables using officer, but now I am using flextable to customise the formatting on individual cells, although they always seem to be in arial font, regardless of the font in the word document (calibri).

Is there a particular style from the word document that flextable uses or is there a command to amend the font.

The closest I have come to an answer so far is the options("ReporteRs-default-font" = "Arial") function. Is there an equivalent command for officer or flextable?

Thanks very much for any guidance.

Comment: There is a function named 'font` in the dev version on Github. Should be on CRAN soon.

Comment: You can also use `style` and provide a `fp_text` object with the correct font name

Comment: does `font()` allow me to change the *default* font for all flextables? I am thinking of something like options(flextable.font = "Times New Roman").

Answer (score 8):

The function `font()` will let you modify an individual cell's font  (but not its color, size, etc.):

```
library(flextable)
library(magrittr) # for %>%
library(officer) # for fp_text
some_data <-iris[c(1,51,101),] 
# example: cell at (1,5)
flextable(some_data) %>% 
  font(i=1, j=5,fontname='Rage Italic')
```

Using `fp_text()` will allow you to modify font, boldness, size, color, etc.

```
flextable(some_data) %>%
  style(i=1,
        j=5,
        pr_t=fp_text(color='purple',font.size=20,
         font.family='Rage Italic') 
        )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need `set_flextable_defaults(font.family = mybetterfont)`

See the [documentation](https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/set_flextable_defaults.html) for details.